# Block access to site from specific IPs?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, ip-address

I'm looking to try and block access from two IP addresses in PHP, preferably notifying them of their blocking.

Is there anyway I can do this or is it just not possible using PHP?

I've seen a JavaScript version of doing it, but if the browser has JavaScript turned off, then surely they'd be able to get around it.

Thanks for any advice/help in advance.

Comment: Just remember that this is almost useless. If someone is really bothering you and your site, they will probably just get more riled up when you ban them from your site. They could use any free webbased proxy like www.hidemyass.com and get a new ip. Or they could be on a dynamic ip connection, and all they have to do to get a new IP is reset their router. It's a start, but don't think that this is an end-all solution, because there really isn't one.

Comment: It's not too much of an issue, it's just a temporary measure. On the plus side I know that the user at the end of the IP address have static IP's and are unable to access web proxy's from their site due to network restrictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in index.php:

```
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '10.0.0.1' || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == '10.0.0.2')
    die('Go away, banned person');
```

Or this version, which becomes more manageable when you start having more than one or two bans:

```
$bans = array(
    '10.0.0.1'  => true,
    '10.0.0.2'  => true,
);
if(!empty($bans[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]))
    die('Go away, banned person');
```

Comment: Technically it should be...  if (isset($bans[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]) && $bans[$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']]) to avoid getting an E_NOTICE

Comment: Yeah.  Sometimes I still think in Perl.  Edited to go one better. :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [page](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/getting-real-ip-address-in-php.html). It contains a function for getting a client's IP address. You can call this on any page and if the IP address matches then display an error message.

However an easier solution is to use  `.htaccess`

Add the following lines to `.htaccess`

```
order allow,deny
deny from xx.xx.xx.xxx
deny from xxx.xxx.xxx
allow from all
```

Where xxx are the IP number you wish to block.

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] should contain the IP.

Answer (score 0):

One place to block is on the web server. Then only allowed IPs would even make it to your site and you wouldn'ty have to introduce any special handling code.

See http://www.iphowto.com/Block_IP_How_To.aspx

Comment: He wanted to notify the user of the ban. Can this be done from the web server?